# Difference between polynomial of degree less than or equal to n and polynomial of degree n

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

I am just starting my linear algebra class and need some help to understand **vector space** for **polynomials**.

Can someone please explain me the *difference between polynomial of degree less than or equal to n and polynomial of degree n*.

Reason for asking: According to the textbook defn. a polynomial of degree less than or equal to n forms a vector space while a polynomial of degree n doesn't. Looking at the example for the 2nd part (polynomial of degree n), I do understand that it doesn't close under addition.

Let P(t) be the set of polynomials of degree n.

Now, for any 2 vectors within P(t):-

p(t)=$4$+ $5t^n$ and q(t)=$3$ − $5t^n$

Then, p(t) + q(t) = 7 which doesn't fall inside P(t). Hence P(t) isn't a vector space.
This should be valid for any n.(as n is the degree of the polynomial)

What I fail to understand is how can then a polynomial of degree less than or equal to n be a vector space? I think I am missing something fundamental here.

Any advice shall be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If both $p(t)$ and $q(t)$ have degree $\le n$ then $p(t)+q(t)$ can never have degree $\gt n$.

Comment: The sum of two polynomials of degree $\le n$ has the degree $\le n$. A polynomial of degree $\le n$ multiplied by a scalar yields a polynomial of degree $\le n$.

Comment: $t^0=1$ so $1\in P(t)$, and therefore $\mathbb R\subset P(t)$. (note that every real number here is associated with the corresponding constant polynomial)

Comment: In your example $p(t)+q(t)=7$, which is a polynomial of degree $\le n$, so no problem arises.

Answer (score 2):

Your misunderstanding is due to the fact that you are considering a polynomial of degree $n$ and a polynomial of degree less than $n$. And we need to consider a set of polynomials. The set of polynomials of degree $n$ does not include polynomials of lesser degree, and the set of polynomials of degree no more than $n$ includes both polynomials of degree $n$ and polynomials of degree $n-1$ and $n-2$, and so on, so when lowering the degree, we do not go beyond the set.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Community: it seems to me that this answer precisely addresses the OP's confusion.